# Laravel 5.5. Recuperar filtro inciial en una vista index a la vuelta de una vista posterior

Tags: laravel-5

Tengo realizado un CRUD con las típicas vistas de create, edit, index y show.
En la vista index tengo definido una campo para realizar un filtro que funciona correctamente. 
Lo que quisiera es saber cómo se hace para que se mantenga el filtro incial de la vista index al volver por ejemplo de la vista de edit una vez modificado un registro.

Actualmente lo que hago en el controlador para la edición es:

```
public function update(bancoRequest $request, $id)
{

    $banco = banco::find($id);
    $banco->fill($request->all());

    if ($banco->isDirty())
    {

        $banco->flag_inactivado = $request->has('flag_inactivado') ? 1 : 0;
        $banco->save();

        flash::success('El banco <b>'.$banco->getCodigoBanco() . ' '. $banco->nombre .'</b> ha sido modificado con éxito.')->important();
    }
    else
    {
         flash::success('Sin cambios que registrar.');
    }

    return redirect()->route('bancos.index');

}
```

pero al redireccionar a la vista index de nuevo se muestran todos los registros de nuevo y yo quiero que se muestren solo los filtrados inicialmente antes de pulsar el botón de edición del registro actualizado.

Answer (score 0):

Para que no pierdas el valor del filtro podrías enviarlo a esa método update y luego de recibirlo cuando llames de nuevo a la vista lo envias:

```
 //Enviar en tu formulario de actualizacion podria ser mediante un input hidden

//En vista
<form method="POST" action="TuControlador@update" >
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"></input>
     <input type="hidden" name="valor_filtro" value="valor_filtro"></input>
      //Demas campos
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
    //En controlador
    public function update(bancoRequest $request, $id)
    {

        $valor_filtro = $request->valor_filtro();//Recibes valor del filtro
        $banco = banco::find($id);
        //$banco->fill($request->all());//Modificar este metodo para enviar los parametros por separado
        $banco->fill([
        'campo_1' => 'valor_campo_1',
        'campo_2' => 'valor_campo_2'
         ]);
         if ($banco->isDirty())
         {

           $banco->flag_inactivado = $request->has('flag_inactivado') ? 1 : 0;
           $banco->save();

           flash::success('El banco <b>'.$banco->getCodigoBanco().''.$banco->nombre .'</b> ha sido modificado con éxito.')->important();
          }
         else
         {
            flash::success('Sin cambios que registrar.');
         }

    //return redirect()->route('bancos.index');
     //Enviar a la vista el valor del filtro
     return view('bancos.index'/*Cambiar bancos.index por el directorio de tu imagen*/, compact('valor_filtro'));

}
```

Luego recibirlo en la vista con blade preguntando con

```
@if(isset($valor_filtro))
   //Asignar valor de tu filtro al elemento html
@else
  //Mostrar filtro por defecto sin valor
@endif
```